# Sampling inquiry for thesis

Tags: correlation, sampling, survey-sampling

I have a mixed-method thesis ongoing and I plan collecting data on my own college (namely college X), specifically from students and faculty members on my department. Evidently, that would be stratified sampling. Specifically, it's the "proportionate stratified sampling". **The study's aim is to determine the knowledge, attitude, and perceptions (KAP) of students and faculty members regarding a certain event and perform correlation of KAP between students and faculty members in *college X* in my department.**

Upon calculating the sample size using the proportional allocation method, (for example) I'll be getting 200 students and 100 faculty members for the survey. I don't have any issue with allocating students in my department but I'll be dealing with the limited amount of faculty members. In our department, there are only 30 faculty members. My thesis adviser suggested that we could allocate other faculty members from other schools with the same department as I am, namely **college A and B**.

**So in summary:**

- Allocate students in **college X** only (since that's the original objective of the study)
- Allocate all 30 faculty members in **college X**, then the remaining 70 would be from **college A and B**.

**My question:**

- Based on my study's objective, would there be a huge error or bias in my study since the objective only state college X? The plan is to solely focus on my college, then get the remaining faculty members from other colleges due to limited number of faculty members. Should I not mention any college at all?
- If you will be suggesting to state college X, A, and B in the objective, that would be a huge error since the students will only be coming from college X and that won't be changed.
- If you will be suggesting to use the disproportionate stratified sampling, there could be a huge error when doing the data analysis. The responses from students could overpower the responses of faculty members.
- If you're thinking to make the students 30 sample size and 30 faculty members, the data analysis would not represent the whole department since there are a thousand of students in my department.

With this, I would like to extend my greatest appreciation to you all. I hope you could answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: (1) Could you please explain what it might mean to "correlate" students and faculties within a specific department?  (2) Why would including subjects from other colleges besides X have any relevance to your study, which appears to concern college X alone?

Comment: (1) I'll be correlating the KAP of students and faculty members regarding a certain event. For instance, correlating Knowledge of students and faculty members. Same with the Attitude and Perceptions. Both students and faculty will be coming from my department (pharmacy).

(2) My thesis adviser suggest that I could allocate faculty members from other colleges (but in pharmacy department as well) since there is only a limited number of faculty members in college X. My adviser is suggesting to allocate some faculty from college A & B to supplement the remaining sample size of faculty members.

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't figure out what kind of relationship or operation you mean by "correlating."  And I still cannot see any justification for augmenting a dataset with data that plausibly would exhibit different characteristics.